# Source for Pelor, the Burning Hate's claim that Pelor refused to destroy a vampire

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, religions-and-deities

In the old Wizards forum post [Pelor, the Burning Hate](https://web.archive.org/web/20150929063558/http://community.wizards.com/comment/13724166), several sources are mentioned for the conjecture put forth, that Pelor is actually evil.  Some of these have specific page references, some do not.  I have looked for the referenced passages, and I have been able to find them all save one.  It is very possible that I am just overlooking it.

What is the page number for the following reference (If it exists)?

> Book of Exalted Deeds: Pelor refused to help destroy a vampire; the paladin was out doing Pelor’s work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Swarm, Divine Wrath:** Book of Exalted Deeds page 188.

> When Thassel Tallstak, a halfling paladin of the church of Pelor, returned home to find his family sucked dry by his vampiric nemisis, he prayed to his god to send a swarm of sunflies to reduce the vampire to ashes—a wish so unbrideled in its hate that Pelor had no choice but to refuse.

Comment: Doesn't this actually support *against* Pelor of the Burning Hate; refusing a hate filled wish?

Comment: @Ruut If you're an evil god who loves hate but is pretending to be a good god of justice, nothing is more hilarious than further fueling a paladin's rage (and potential to fall) by refusing his request to destroy an evil creature "because the paladin is too hateful".

Comment: @ObliviousSage I like that.

Comment: I feel strange about playing a Cleric of Pelor now.